# cURL acessar https

Tags: php, javascript, libcurl

Boa tarde, preciso acessar o seguinte link https://www.reneg.bvfinanceira.com.br/assessoria/

e nele preciso que meu sistema em php inseira o login e a senha.

O problema: 
   1- Minha pagina fica em braco quado chamo este link... mas testei o código com outros sites e funcionou.
   2- Quando acesso outro site consigo mudar o valor dos inputs e tals, mas não consigo dar o click no botão submit.

O que preciso:
   1- |Conseguir acessar o site da bv, acho que deve ser algo de segurança https pois vi isso pesquisando.
   2- Dar submit no form ou click no botão pois eh a única coisa que não manipulo na pagina...

obs: estou usando javascript para inserir os dados nos inputs e com o `document.getElementById("input_login").value = "meu_login"` funciona,
mas `document.getElementById("botao_submit").submit()` nao funciona.

Obrigado.

Comment: Você tem um erro de sintaxe, você deve usar `document.getElementById("botao_submit").submit()`, remova a acentuação do `id` do botão e coloque as letras maiúsculas na função `getElementById`.

Comment: Boa trade, obrigado pela respota, porém no meu cod esta correto só aqui não escrevi com maiucsula.

Comment: Ah uma coisa que não notei antes, você deve usar a função `submit()` em um formulário, pelo seu código você tenta dar o submit no botão, não é? Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit

Comment: Eu já tentei 
document.getElementById("botao_submit").submit()
document.getElementById("botao_submit").click()
ai nada ocorre...

document.getElementById("form_submit").click()
document.getElementById("form_submit").submit()
aqui parece q a pagina fica dando reload freneticamente mas o form esta codificado para redirecionar para outra pag